# CacheManager and Dispose

Tags: c#, caching, dispose, cachemanager

I'm going to use the [CacheManager](https://github.com/MichaCo/CacheManager) which should handle my caching for me. 
 When do I have to dispose it?

Is it meant to be created every time I access the cache with a using statement?

In this case I would have to write my initialization every time?

```
var cache = CacheFactory.Build("cache1", settings =>
{
    settings
        .WithSystemRuntimeCacheHandle("handle1")
            .EnablePerformanceCounters()
            .WithExpiration(ExpirationMode.Absolute, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10));
});
```

Or how am I supposed to use/dispose it? I'm actually getting code analysis warnings that I should dispose it.

Comment: I does think that you will ever dispose it, as it will be automatically handled. May be we can dispose in application_shutdown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is simply no ;)

You don't want to dispose the CacheManager instance. It is even more common to keep a static instance of it in your application and only create the CacheManager once.

That's because creation of the CacheManager and the handles which creates instances of the cache clients and maybe opens connections to distributed caches, is very expensive and must be done only once. From there on, it should work and stay as a static reference.

It is also a good practice to simply use an IoC Container and register it as singleton. Then the IoC Container might handle the disposal for you anyways.

> Is it meant to be created every time I access the cache with a using statement?

No this should not be done.